# How can I add dates to column but repeat each 24 times, in Excel?

Tags: excel

Here is a sample from the data that I am looking at.

```
Hour Index  Visits
    0   67
    1   22
    2   111
    3   22
    4   0
    5   0
    6   22
    7   44
    8   0
    9   89
    10  22
    11  111
    12  44
    13  89
    14  44
    15  111
    16  177
    17  89
    18  44
    19  44
    20  89
    21  22
    22  89
    23  44
    24  133
    25  44
    26  22
    27  22
    28  44
    29  22
    30  44
    31  44
    32  22
```

what I want to do is add another column that contains dates starting with Monday which is repeated 24 times then go to Tuesday (repeated 24 times) and so on.  So the result should look like:

```
Hour Index  Visits  Day
0   67  MONDAY
1   22  MONDAY
2   111 MONDAY
3   22  MONDAY
4   0   MONDAY
5   0   MONDAY
6   22  MONDAY
7   44  MONDAY
8   0   MONDAY
9   89  MONDAY
10  22  MONDAY
11  111 MONDAY
12  44  MONDAY
13  89  MONDAY
14  44  MONDAY
15  111 MONDAY
16  177 MONDAY
17  89  MONDAY
18  44  MONDAY
19  44  MONDAY
20  89  MONDAY
21  22  MONDAY
22  89  MONDAY
23  44  MONDAY
24  133 TUESDAY
25  44  TUESDAY
26  22  TUESDAY
27  22  TUESDAY
28  44  TUESDAY
29  22  TUESDAY
30  44  TUESDAY
31  44  TUESDAY
32  22  TUESDAY
```

I know how to get the dates to increment, but not repeat 24 times then increment.  Can someone show me how to do this with Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this formula (I suppose that your Hour column starts from `A2` cell):

```
=TEXT(1+MOD(1+INT(A2/24),7),"dddd")
```

Note, that formula works well if your excel dates starts from 01.01.1900 (which is usually default for excel on PC). 
If you are using 1904 date system, you should use next formula:

```
=TEXT(2+MOD(1+INT(A2/24),7),"dddd")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:  `=UPPER(TEXT(DAY(2+A2/24),"dddd"))`. The first `2` is to control when the sequence starts.