# Excel add column starting at 1 and increments to 24 then resets

Tags: excel

I need to add a column in excel that begins at 1 (at say cell A1) and increments until it hits 24, then resets to one after that and repeats the process. Can someone tell me the formula for this? thanks

Comment: huh? Not the same question and not the same answer.

Comment: I would agree that this is closely related to [Excel Add date column with dates repeated 24 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974471/excel-add-date-column-with-dates-repeated-24-times) and [Excel Add Dates to Column but repeat each 24 times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960023/excel-add-dates-to-column-but-repeat-each-24-times), but I guess they are legitimate as separate questions (so "possible duplicate" may seem a little hard)... It is not very clear what the research effort on the side of the OP was here, but this is just average in SO.

Comment: well I was not able to extrapolate one answer from the other. So what was I supposed to do?  If they were the same I think I would be able to do that.

Comment: OK I could have said I did a google search and could not find my answer, but I don't think that would have added anything useful. Sometimes you must learn by asking questions if you are not getting anywhere on your own.

Comment: OK so are you saying that they are not duplicates anymore?

Comment: @user1893354 - One of the answers you received (and accepted) for another question involves the function `MOD`. Did you read [the first hit on Google](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelsmathfunctions/qt/2010-03-07-excel-2007-mod-function.htm) for "excel mod" (or, any other about MOD)? I wonder what did you specifically Google that did not lead you to the answer, and what did you try.

Comment: @user1893354 -  It is very likely that if you Google "your question" you will not find "your answer" (you might be lucky, anyway). But prior to asking in SO you are supposed to do more than that. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following simple formula:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(), 24) = 0, 24,MOD(ROW(), 24))
```

Comment: If I replace COLUMN() with ROW() then I get what I want. Maybe I wasn't clear. If you change it I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
=MOD(ROW()-1,24)+1
```

If you want your first row to be, say 3 (i.e., cell A3 containing 1), then use

```
=MOD(ROW()-ROW(A$3),24)+1
```

In both cases, copy and paste below in the range needed.